# resolve XSS issue on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, xss, sanitize, javascript-injection, html-safe

Example: If we store `<script>alert(299792458)</script>` as a first name input, the value is getting accepted and stored.

When we display the data, an alert pops up. I understand that it's a Cross-Site Scripting (XSS). I have gone through http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-scripting-xss but I wan't able to understand.

All I need to do is make sure that alert doesn't happen. So, what's a best option. Sanitize first name while saving it (or) use html_safe when displaying it.

Comment: Please add some more code to your post. What is your "first name input"? And if your "display" code is just `<%= first_name %>`, ERB or the equivalent is supposed to escape the `<` and `>` into `&lt;` and `&gt;`, neutralizing the script.

Comment: [`html_safe`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-html_safe) is the exact wrong thing to do `html_safe` marks the string as being safe (which appears to be what you are doing since the alert shows) remove this call and the string will be displayed appropriately as @Phlip mentioned. Alternatively you could use `<%= sanitize(first_name) %>`

Answer (score 1):

I used this function and it worked as expected.

```
CGI::escapeHTML(user.firstname)
```

On display page, it showed `<script>alert("123");</script>` but the script didn't run because it escaped the tags.